# Por qué no me carga el valor del input

Tags: javascript

*Tengo este código que **genera inputs** y estoy realizando código también para eliminarlos, pero no puedo obtener el valor del input con id `idel` , que es el que dice `'to delete'`*

**Realmente, nosé cual es el error, si alguien me ayuda a detectarlo.**

```js
/* Input generator code */

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',igenerator);

function igenerator(){
 var bg = document.getElementById('b-generate'),numbers = document.getElementById('inputgen');
 bg.addEventListener('click',function(){
      for(let j=1;j<=numbers.value;j++){
          inputCreate(j);
      }
 });

 function inputCreate(j){
          var inputGenerated = document.createElement('INPUT');
          inputGenerated.setAttribute('id','generated'+j);
          inputGenerated.setAttribute('type','text');
          inputGenerated.placeholder = inputGenerated.getAttribute('id'); /* Placeholder with ID attribute */
          inputGenerated.style.top = 40 + Math.pow(j,2) + 'px';
          inputGenerated.style.marginLeft = '2%';
          document.body.appendChild(inputGenerated);
 }
 var tdel = document.getElementById("idel").value; /* Aqui empiezo a intentar obtenerlo */
 var bdel = document.getElementById('b-delete');
     bdel.addEventListener('click',function(){
              alert(tdel);
     });
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>zero to hero ?</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
<script src="igenerator.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- I define the default css values !-->
<style>
body { color: gray; margin: 0;}
.title { font-family: monospace; color: black; font-size: 25px; margin-left: 35vw;} 
.ms { font-family: monospace;}
</style>
<body>
  <b class="title">Javascript Input generator(and can be deleted)</b>
  <hr></hr>
   <label for="inputgen"> Number of inputs to be generated: </label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="to add" id='inputgen'> <input type="button" value="Generate" id='b-generate'>

   <label for="idel"> Number of inputs to be deleted: </label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="to delete" id="idel"> <input type="button" value="Delete" id="b-delete">
   <hr></hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El problema aquí:

```
var tdel = document.getElementById("idel").value; /* Aqui empiezo a intentar obtenerlo */
var bdel = document.getElementById('b-delete');    
bdel.addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert(tdel);
});
```

#### Estás cogiendo un valor `pasado` undefined y no el actual.

```
var bdel = document.getElementById('b-delete');

    bdel.addEventListener('click',function(){
         /* Aquí cogerás el actual */
         var tdel = document.getElementById("idel").value;
         alert(tdel);
    });
```

Comment: Genial, gracias dddenis !